# Play framework - overwrite onRouteRequest in java

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I would like to bypass play 2 routes and return my own handler in Global, looking for help on how can we do that. Preferably in Java, but if thats not possible, scala is fine.

```
public Handler onRouteRequest(play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader request){
//return my Handler here, not the super.onRouteRequest
}
```

Comment: Have you found a valid answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by "Overriding onRequest".

```
`@Overridepublic
Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
   System.out.println("before each request..." + request.toString());
   return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
}`
```

Above code is directly taken for Play framework [site](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaInterceptors)(for Java).

For Scala here is the [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaInterceptors).

Comment: I don't think there is an onRouteRequest that takes two parameters: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings